# Is it possible to make Babel transpile only tags leaving off JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am learning React, and one thing I'd like to ask is whether it's possible to make Babel transpile only tags in JSX file?
Say, I have the following method in component:

```js
handleProductUpVote(productId) {
    const nextProducts = this.state.products.map(product => {
        if (product.id === productId) {
            return Object.assign({}, product, {
                votes: product.votes + 1,
            });
        } else {
            return product;
        }
    });
    // Other code
```

Instead of this boilerplate code, I wanted to use object spread operator which narrows down code to single line:

```js
const nextProducts = this.state.products.map(product =>
   product.id === product.id ? { ...{}, ...product, votes: ++product.votes } : product);
```

However, I get the following error:

```
babel.min.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: https://localhost:44376/js/app.js: Unexpected token (18:32)
  16 | handleProductUpVote(productId) {
  17 |  const nextProducts = this.state.products.map(product =>
> 18 |      product.id === product.id ? { ...{}, ...product, votes: ++product.votes } : product);
     |                                    ^
```

As far as I understood, Babel compiler wasn't able to transpile this code. So, is it possible to say Babel to deal only with tags, leaving out JavaScript as is?

Comment: Why did you not use [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/)? It looks like you misconfigured webpack or babel or both yet did not tag the question as such.

Comment: @HMR I just began learning and I want to focus on React itself rather the tooling. Please, if you know how to instruct Babel to process tags only, I'm all ears.  I'm using ASP.NET Core.

Comment: `I want to focus on React itself rather the tooling.` > proceeds to ask about tooling. I assume asp.net is used for json endpoints and can be configured with [proxy](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/) if you used create-react-app and run dev server.